# SQL help to insert into daily sale table from slaes table plus associated dimensions

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

Still learning developer, and SQL, trying to figure out the best way of doing this.
I want to run a procedure that will take all of the records in SALES, find the associated TERMINALID, MERCHANTID, MERCHANT.BANKACC, MERCHANT.PHONE, and insert them into the DAILYSALE table (which I've created with all the appropriate columns).

[image: simplified ERD]

Just still trying to get my head around the simplest way of doing this. I know it's not particularly complicated, but I'm still in the beginner stages of learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO DAILYSALE
(RECEIPTNO, TERMINALID, MERCHANTID, BANKACC, PHONE)
SELECT s.RECEIPTNO, s.TERMINALID, p.MERCHANTID, m.BANKACC, m.PHONE
FROM SALE s
INNER JOIN POSID p ON s.TERMINALID = p.TERMINALID
INNER JOIN MERCHANT m ON p.MERCHANTID = m.MERCHANTID
```